# Application Force stop on GenyMotion

Tags: java, android, genymotion, forceclose

I'm using Genymotion to test my application. Everything was good until I decided to change windows. So I changed my windows and start installing apps and also Genymotion.

But since I changed windows anytime I want to run my application on Genymotion (The app I created in android studio) I get force close and I don't know why.

I searched online but didn't get any helpful answer.

**How should I fix this?**

My Logcat:

```
10-04 05:41:01.944    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar D/Sentry﹕    Adding request - e426abdc-b680-4917-9ab5-32270a189043 #R 271
10-04 05:41:02.065    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp   target GC heap from 97MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:02.124    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 110MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:02.153    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:02.200    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar D/Sentry﹕ Adding request - 7f23d887-a032-4106-b45d-0eec6b6b3486 #R 272
10-04 05:41:02.211    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Alloc  partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3895(184KB) AllocSpace objects,   4(41MB) LOS objects, 22% free, 54MB/70MB, paused 55us total 7.144ms
10-04 05:41:02.396    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 97MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:02.464    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 110MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:02.485    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:02.529    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar D/Sentry﹕  Adding request - f7871860-de44-4281-9ea3-5d5135e0bb3d #R 273
10-04 05:41:02.705    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 97MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:02.759    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 110MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:02.782    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:02.825    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar D/Sentry﹕ Adding request - eec764ad-0561-4413-8000-425119e47a04 #R 274
10-04 05:41:02.836    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 10.363ms for cause Alloc
10-04 05:41:03.008    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 97MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:03.058    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 110MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:03.078    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:03.140    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 18.718ms for cause Alloc
10-04 05:41:03.141    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar D/Sentry﹕ Adding request - 86e198d8-8678-4bab-8080-fddfa99b1057 #R 275
10-04 05:41:03.329    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 97MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:03.376    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 110MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:03.397    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:03.445    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar D/Sentry﹕ Adding request - 5df4352f-2924-4cef-b2c2-0612224195f0 #R 276
10-04 05:41:03.622    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 97MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:03.672    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 110MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:03.698    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:03.747    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar D/Sentry﹕ Adding request - 650c88b3-397b-4231-860c-c42659eda941 #R 277
10-04 05:41:03.932    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 97MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:03.993    2597-2609/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 110MB to 96MB
10-04 05:41:04.018    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 17MB allocation
10-04 05:41:04.024    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects,     16% free, 78MB/94MB, paused 67us total 5.219ms
10-04 05:41:04.024    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 18275370 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 17MB until OOM"
10-04 05:41:04.024    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-04 05:41:04.024    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.persianrap.aliakhgar, PID: 2597
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 18275370 byte   allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 17MB until OOM
        at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:400)
        at   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:633)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:663)
        at org.json.JSONStringer.toString(JSONStringer.java:430)
        at org.json.JSONArray.toString(JSONArray.java:586)
        at co.ronash.pushe.util.d.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.db.b.b(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.l.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.l.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.handlers.SentryHandler.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.e(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.c(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.a.c(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.i.d(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.handlers.SentryHandler.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.e(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.c(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.a.c(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.i.d(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.handlers.SentryHandler.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.e(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.c(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.a.c(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.i.d(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.handlers.SentryHandler.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.e(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.c(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.a.c(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.i.d(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.handlers.SentryHandler.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.e(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.c(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.a.c(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.i.d(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.handlers.SentryHandler.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.e(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.c(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.a.c(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.i.d(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.handlers.SentryHandler.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.e(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.log.h.c(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.a.c(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.ronash.pushe.task.i.a(Unknown So
10-04 05:41:05.935    2597-2597/org.persianrap.aliakhgar I/Process﹕ Sending   signal. PID: 2597 SIG: 9
```

Comment: you are creating an 18M String. that's not a good idea

Comment: well i didnt do it! the problem is that i was using GCM while google services wasnt installed! @njzk2

Comment: something in the `co.ronash.pushe.util` package is, somehow

Comment: somehow needed Google services ;) @njzk2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your manifest and try

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

The line         `android:largeHeap="true"` is important, add that

you got   `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 18275370 byte   allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 17MB until OOM` error which means you are out of heap memory

**Or maybe you must not have installed google play services in the genny emulator**

Comment: nope! no working! again force stop and sometimes hang up.... is there any way?  and i have this problem just on geny i think... i have tested my app on P7 and had no problem... What to do?!

Comment: oh yeah! im using GCM and is it bcz of this?

Comment: you must not have installed google play services in the genny emulator

Comment: i installed google play services and it worked out! Thaaaanks! I wish i code vote u up twice! Plz edit your soultion , i'll check it as the answer

Comment: you can upvote it with your current rep points, i was able to do it